# Why won't IE display my WPF component?

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, xaml, blend

I made a component using a WPF control library component. In blend and Visual studio it's working as expected, but I can't make it work on IE when I open the xaml file with IE.

You're probably asking yourself "why would he need to make it work with IE?". It's simple: we are using a HMI SCADA software: Zenon (Copa Data). This software is supposed to support WPF components. To verify if the component will work in that software they tell to test it with IE in their documentation.

Of course, I tried to import the WPF component directly in Zenon before testing it with IE but it's not working.

Here is the xaml file:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:ListeImitationMobileWPF;assembly=ListeImitationMobileWPF"
        Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <lib:MaListeMaintenance/>
</UserControl>
```

ListeImitationMobileWPF is the WPF control library which contains the component "MaListeMaintenance".

The error from IE: "The tag 'MaListeMaintenance' doesn't exist in the XML namespace ''clr-namespace:ListeImitationMobileWPF;assembly=ListeImitationMobileWPF'."

(Translation from french, I don't know if it's the exact english error message, original one:System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: La balise 'MaListeMaintenance' n'existe pas dans l'espace de noms XML 'clr-namespace:ListeImitationMobileWPF;assembly=ListeImitationMobileWPF'.)

Edit: I tried to put the .dll in the same folder but it's still giving me this error

Edit2: More information: The lib has been compiled with the 4.5.1 dotnet framework, VS/blend 2013. If you need more information ask me about it. Thank you

Edit3: Some more information: The lib only contains a UserControl which contains a Button. Nothing else. IE seems to be unable to look in my dll, so is Zenon. In a standard project you have to add the library to project references so he can find it. I don't know how I could mimic this without a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem is that Zenon can't handle newer dotnet framework version than 3.5. Thank you all for reading my problem.